# How to get which date is on particular saturday or sunday of a month

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can I find the date of a day that is on which dates the saturdays and sundays of a specific month fall
For e.g Consider the month of JANUARY-2017. The following dates are weekends

```
7/1/2017 - Saturday

14/1/2017 - Saturday

21/1/2017 - Saturday

28/1/2017 - Saturday
```

---

```
1/1/2017 - Sunday

8/1/2017 - Sunday

15/1/2017 - Sunday

22/1/2017 - Sunday

29/1/2017 - Sunday
```

I want SQL query for this such that when I give Month and Year as input it should give me all the above dates (only dates of saturday and sunday) as output

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In the 4th line, you can put year/month combination. I have used `2017-02` for example.

```
SELECT TRUNC(dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1 AS mdate
,to_char(TRUNC(dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1,'DY' ) as m_day
FROM 
(select to_date('2017-02','YYYY-MM') as dt from dual) --this is where you can put year/month
where to_char(TRUNC(dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1,'DY' ) in ('SAT','SUN')
CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(dt, 'MM') + LEVEL - 1, 'MM') = TRUNC(dt, 'MM')
```

Output

```
MDATE       M_DAY 
04-FEB-2017 SAT
05-FEB-2017 SUN
11-FEB-2017 SAT
12-FEB-2017 SUN
18-FEB-2017 SAT
19-FEB-2017 SUN
25-FEB-2017 SAT
26-FEB-2017 SUN
```

Comment: Sorry to bother but can I get the same query as in sql server query format. I am beginner to this field

Answer (score 0):

A simple tweak in SQL query can provide you the required output. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT A.DT,
  TO_CHAR(A.DT,'FmDay') DAY
FROM
  (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate,'MONTH')+level DT
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'fmDD')
  )a
WHERE TO_CHAR(a.dt,'FmDAY') IN ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY');
```

Comment: How can you do this for a range of dates instead of just a month? Thanks for your time and expertise

Answer (score 0):

I will do some major changes above code
we are get the all sundays and saturdays in year

```
SELECT TRUNC(dt, 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1 AS mdate
,to_char(TRUNC(dt, 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1,'DY' ) as m_day
FROM
(select to_date('2020-01','YYYY-MM') as dt from dual) --this is where you can put year/month
where to_char(TRUNC(dt, 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1,'DY' ) in ('SAT','SUN')
CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(dt, 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1, 'yyyy') = TRUNC(dt, 'yyyy')
```